# How to use while loop and range in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am learning Python and I have homework that I cant do without help.
Here is homework:

define a variable and set it to the integer number of 10000
use a while loop to count down this number until it reaches 0
each iteration of the loop must decrease the number by a value of 100 thru 10, repeat this if we have not reached zero
display each new value of the variable
when the variable reaches zero or goes below zero the program will end
never let a negative value display to the user.
I have no idea how to do it with while loop. I have done this with for loop.
Thank you!

What I've tried:

```
x=int(10000) 
while x > 0: 
    print (x) 
    x-=100
```

Comment: Please could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: *Here is my homework*, Here are our rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You'll get answers if you post your attempt at working code, but unfortunately stackoverflow is not a code writing service, but exists to help people get their code working. Since there's no code in the question you may find that it gets closed unless you edit it.

Comment: I try something like this
x=int(10000)
while x > 0:
 print (x)
 x-=100

Comment: @Boki_Moki I've edited your code in your question, what do you think is wrong with that approach? and how does it differ from your desired output?

Comment: I done the same but I need for numbers after 100 to be decrease by 10. Something like this The last few numbers displayed should be:
65
50
36
23
11

Comment: @Boki_Moki if you want the numbers after 100 to be decreased by 10 then it should be 90,80,70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not need to cast the `int` in your line number 1.

Change this:

```
x=int(10000)
```

to this:

```
x = 10000
```

2. Your code is fine, if the intention is to print the original value inside the loop and the last value i.e. 0 after the iterations, you need to print the current value afterwards.

   `print(x)`

Hence:

```
x=10000
while x > 0:
    print (x)
    x -= 100

print(x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
10000
9900
9800
9700
9600
.
.
.
300
200
100
0
```

EDIT:

OP:  *I need for numbers after 100 to be decrease by 10.*

You need a `if-else` condition to handle the numbers after 100.

Something like:

```
if x <= 100:
    x -= 10
else:
    x -= 100
```

Hence:

```
x=10000
while x > 0:
    print (x)
    if x <= 100:
        x -= 10
    else:
        x -= 100   
print(x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
10000
9900
9800
9700
.
.
.
300
200
100
90
.
.
30
20
10
0
```

Comment: This is solution. Thank you. I need if else for numbers after 100. Thank again

Comment: @Boki_Moki You're welcome, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask a better formatted question next time, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the below code..This code will reduce the number by 100 if its greater than 10000 and reduce by a random number between 1-10 if its lesser than 100.

```
from random import randint


number = 10000
while (number > 0):
    print(number)
    if number > 100:
        number = number - 100
    else:
        number = number - randint(1,10)
```

from this you will get your desired output .. `if number >= 100`

```
9900
9800
9700
....
300
200
100
```

and `if number < 100`
you will get

```
95
90
83
..
15
12
2
1
```

Comment: he mentioned `display each new value of the variable`. here the variable number gets its new value after the `number=number-100`.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with something like this?

```
val = 10000
while val > 0:
        print(val)
        val = val - 100
print(0)
```

You can subtract by a random number between 10 and 100:

```
import random
val = 10000
while val > 0:
        print(val)
        val = val - random.randint(10, 100)
print(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code as per i can interpret

```
#Declare the first variable
a=10000
while a > 0:
    print (a)
    if a <= 100:
        a -= 10
    else:
        a -= 100   
print(a)
#This is the while loop which you should use to display all the numbers
```

Let me know if you need anything more.